# Вывод данных многомерного массива

Tags: массивы

Друзья, какой то страшный массив попался с непонятным для меня ["@attributes"], не получается вывести данные из массива в формате:

> ["date"]["time"]["amount"]["description"]

Помогите, пожалуйта.

```
{array(3) {
   ["@attributes"]=> array(1) {
    ["version"]=> string(3) "1.0" }
["auction"]=> array(2) {
    ["id"]=> string(6) "ХХХ" ["signature"]=> string(40) "ХХХХ" }
["data"]=> array(2) {
    ["oper"]=> string(3) "cmt" ["info"]=> array(1) {
        ["statements"]=> array(2) {
            ["@attributes"]=> array(3) {
                ["status"]=> string(9) "excellent" ["credits"]=> string(7) "ХХХХ" ["debets"]=> string(8) "ХХХХ" } ["statement"]=> array(22) {
                [0]=> array(1) {
                    ["@attributes"]=> array(9) {
                       ["appcode"]=> string(6) "ХХХХХ" **["date"]**=> string(10) "2018-02-12" **["time"]**=> string(8) "21:56:00" **["amount"]**=> string(12) "100" **["description"]**=> string(147) "description1" } } [1]=> array(1) {
                    ["@attributes"]=> array(9) {
                       ["appcode"]=> string(6) "ХХХХХ" **["date"]**=> string(10) "2018-02-12" **["time"]**=> string(8) "21:46:00" **["amount"]**=> string(12) "200" **["description"]**=> string(147) "description2" } } [2]=> array(1) {
                    ["@attributes"]=> array(9) {
                        ["appcode"]=> string(6) "ХХХХХ" **["date"]**=> string(10) "2018-02-12" **["time"]**=> string(8) "21:36:00" **["amount"]**=> string(12) "300" **["description"]**=> string(147) "description3" } } } } } } } -@attributes </pre>
```

Comment: Откула у вас такой страшный массив взялся? На каком языке хотите вывести данные?

Comment: Угадай мелодию. Развиваем телепатические способности.

Comment: Это данные через api с одного ресурса, они обновляются. На php ннннадо)